# Get search.php results in header.php?

Tags: loop, templates, search, headers

I want one image in header.php to change for different pages.

The function in header.php looks like that:

```
if(is_archive()):
  //change image to "Archives"
endif;
if(is_404()):
 //change image to "404"
endif;
```

Now, is it possible to check if page is the search page AND what's the search string AND how many posts were found?

So what I want to do is basically:

```
if(is_search()):
 //change image to "Search" AND echo %s
endif;
if(is_search_empty()): //yes I made this up
 //change image to "Nothing found" AND echo $
endif;
```

Is it even possible outside the search.php page loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now, is it possible to check if page is the search page

```
is_search()
```

> AND what's the search string

```
is_search() AND print get_query_var( 's' )
```

> AND how many posts were found?

```
is_search() AND print $GLOBALS['wp_query']->number_posts()
```

… or if you got a custom query…

```
$my_query = new WP_Query( array( /* whatever args */ ) );
is_search() AND print $my_query->number_posts()
```

Comment: Thank you, but checking how many posts were found still doesn't seem to work for me. I have standard `if( have_posts() ) :` loop in search.php and your first code returns `Fatal error: Call to undefined method WP_Query::found_posts()`.

Comment: Try `$GLOBALS['wp_query']->number_posts()`. Have written it from the backside of my head and not sure what the method name is.

Comment: `$GLOBALS['wp_query']->have_posts()` was the answer, thanks a lot, Franz!